# failed with Server min and max wire version are incompatible (6,6) with client min wire version (0,5)",

Tags: mongodb-replica-set

want to implement master slave two ubuntu machine having same mongoshell version 3.4.19 but gives error "failed with Server min and max wire version are incompatible (6,6) with client min wire version (0,5)","

while rs.add("ip:port")